# Xamarin.Forms.Labs Is Missing

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Getting "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Labs' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." at runtime though I have the nuget packages for Lab installed. Running VS 13 -- anyone know a fix?

This is a Xamarin.Forms project on VC 2013, I have installed the packages via nuget, which appear on disk.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you have to make sure that all the references have the true flag for "copy to.." Something funky must have happened in VS, as I believe true is the default.